# How to get my if statement for b working?

Tags: python-3.x

I have managed to get my if statement working for part of it but the other part (the code below) just stops running

I have tried if `(starting == "A") or (starting == "A"):` which worked for another part of the code but not for `if (starting == "B") or (starting == "b")`:

```
starting = input("""**********      Price Calculator      **********
                    A = Calculating discounts
                    B = Best buy
                    Type in your choice: """)

if (starting == "B") or (starting == "b"): # This should go to the next line but instead ends

    yesno2 = ("""**********      Price Calculator      **********
              A = Comparing mass (grams)
              B = Comparing quantity
              Type in your choice: """)  # This part is here to show what it should show
```

There is no error message but the code just ends even if I type b which it should instead go to the next line of code

Answer (score 0):

There is no mistake in your code, that is the reason why it does not throw any error.

You initialized the variable yesno2 with a string, but you forgot to print it. Just add the following line under your variable initialization, it should do the job.

```
print(yesno2)
```

Comment: I didn't notice that I had no print there, thanks for pointing that out.